# How the wxDialog Destroy function work

Tags: wxwidgets

All:

I got one question about the the wxDialog Destry():

Suppose I make a dialog which inheritate from wxDialog like:

```
 wxMyDialog dlg = new wxMyDialog(.....the pararmeter.....)
```

and inside wxMyDialog, there are some wxwidgets pointers like wxbutton*, wxBoxSizer* ....

I read some tutorials, most of them do not mention what happen to those inside pointers, so I wonder, when I call `dlg->Destroy()`, can all those pointers be automatically free? Can someone tell me what happen behind Destroy()?

or

if not, how can I free them mannually?

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the widget pointer inside your dialog, you pass a pointer to parent dialog.  The parent keeps these pointers, and when the parent dialog is destoyed, delete is called on those pointers.  So, you see, every window cleans up its own children.

Bottom line: children are 'owned' by their parents and you never need to worry about tidying up after them - the parents do it.

A couple of special cases:

1. If you pass NULL as the parent window to the widget creator, this means that the widget belongs to the desktop window, not the application.  You should NOT do this for anything other that a top level window!
2. You do not pass the parent window pointer to the constructor of a sizer.  Instead you pass the sizer pointer to the parent window's SetSizer method - which has the same effect, the parent windows owns the sizer and deletes it when the window is destroyed.

Comment: thanks, but I wonder what happened to widgets like wxBoxSizer? I read from many tutorial, they are not given a parents pointer prarmeter either, but still works?

Comment: When you call setSizer on the parent window, the parent then owns the sizer and it will auto delete it as described in the docs.  http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowsetsizer